# Why is alpha the criteria for rejecting $H_0$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, p-value

1. We reject $H_0$ with criteria **$\alpha$**, saying that the probability of falsely rejecting $H_0$ (p value) is less than the probability of making a type I error that we permit ($\alpha$).
2. **$\alpha$** is the probability that we **'reject'** $H_0$ when assumptions and $H_0$ are TRUE. (Thus the probability that we permit type I error)
3. The criteria for the very **'rejection'** is $\alpha$.

It looks like circular reasoning... in that the definition of $\alpha$ contains the concept of 'rejection' and the definition of 'rejection' is that 'do not accept $H_0$ based on $\alpha$.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Typically we first choose alpha, on a way that’s not related to the data at hand, then we apply the test.

Comment: Thank you. I understood your point. So the alpha is just the pre-set borderline value that exist before any data, right?

Comment: @utobi, make this an answer :-)

Comment: Definition 1. is not correct as it implies an unconditional probability.  $\alpha$ is the probability of rejecting $H_0$ when **any** assertion of a non-zero effect is by definition false.  And the way most practitioners do statistical tests results in $\alpha = \Pr(p < 0.05 | H_{0})$.

Answer (score 3):

Mainstream theory of statistical tests - at least in the spirit of Neyman and Pearson - tells us, among other things that, for any given significant level $\alpha$, our test must be *valid*. This means that the rate of Type I errors under any probability model in the null hypothesis is less than or equal to $\alpha$.

From this theory, we know there is a trade-off between $\alpha$ and the size of type II error, and we have no hints whatsoever about how to fix $\alpha$.

However, in most applications, making a type I error, e.g. doing a wrong discovery, is more problematic than making a type II error, e.g. failing to recognize a genuine discovery, thus practitioners opt for choosing a small $\alpha$ (conventionally 1% or 5%), perform their tests and get the deserved size of type II error. We could decrease the size of type II error by increasing the sample size, or by performing sequential experiments, but that's not always feasible.

Thus, in summary, when performing a hypothesis test, the level $\alpha$ is (arbitrarily) chosen beforehand.

Comment: Not sure about the "is much worse" part.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, I have in mind the classical example of the judicial process. In this context, we would arguably have $H_0:$ "defendant is innocent" against $H_1:$ "defendant is guilty". For many people, declaring an innocent defendant to be guilty (with the death penalty), aka type I error, is much worse than declaring him/her innocent when he/she is guilty, type II error.

Comment: @utobi you've made the common mistake described [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/alpha.html).  Frequentist statistical ideas don't lend themselves to evidential statements.  In the judicial process one is interested only in probabilities that are unconditional on any unknowable assumption and are only conditional on the data. Pr(defendent is guilty | data) and not Pr(defendent is guilty | data and something we assume about the defendent's guilt).

Comment: "Mistake" is a little harsh.  I should have said that this is a common point of confusion and an example where conditioning on what you are trying to determine is not extremely helpful.

Comment: I take it! The link seems an interesting lengthy read.